# How to search all text without separation by spacing in full text search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for full text search

```
select title from products where MATCH (title) AGAINST ('green book')
```

but this query return this products

```
+-------------+------------------+
|      id     |      title       |
----------------------------------
|      34     |    green book    |
----------------------------------
|      84     |    green shirt   |
----------------------------------
|      22     |    red book      |
----------------------------------
```

I use `Like%` operation its returns the correct data but I need rank ability and better performance because this column have more than 2000 length.

My expected output:

```
+-------------+------------------+
|      id     |      title       |
----------------------------------
|      34     |    green book    |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: `select name from products where MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+green +book')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heree are two possibilitys how twpo do it

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `title` VARCHAR(11)
> , 
> FULLTEXT(title));
>
> INSERT INTO products
>   (`id`, `title`)
> VALUES
>   ('34', 'green book'),
>     ('35', 'book green'),
>   ('84', 'green shirt'),
>   ('22', 'red book');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM products WHERE match(title) against('+green +book' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
> AND title like '%green book%'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title     
> -: | :---------
> 34 | green book
> ```

> ```
>   SELECT * FROM products WHERE match(title) against('"green book"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title     
> -: | :---------
> 34 | green book
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=89588bb0137bc1a3f00a7c868fd0c8bf)*

Answer (score 1):

First, you are lucky that neither of your search terms are stop words or too short.

Second, you need to review how to use [`match()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).  *Any* match in the text is going to return a value greater than 0 -- in your case, either or both words.  Having multiple copies of a word might increase the score.

You can modify the words used for the search by using `+` -- that requires their presence.  And is what Luuk pointed out in a comment except you need boolean mode:

```
where MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+green +book' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation